# nginx not working with gunicorn for external IP's

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, gunicorn

I am using nginx and gunicorn for a django application on AWS.
Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mywebsite

```html
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/ubuntu/mywebsite/staticfiles/;
    }
}
```

The Gunicorn command I am running.

```html
gunicorn mywebsite.wsgi:application --bind=127.0.0.1:8001
```

All this is on AWS

The problem is I can access the website by going to mywebsite.com and it works as expected on any machine on my home network but other people(not on my home network) still get welcome to nginx.

I have the domain mywebsite.com pointed to my was elastic IP
I also have port 80 open on AWS.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe they access www.mywebsite.com ? Try other network and let me know if there are any problem

Comment: Sorry I am very new to this. So sever name will be different for mywebsite.com and www.mywebsite.com. Is there a way to add both of them.

Comment: Put it like this `server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are high posibility that the other person outside your network will access www.mywebsite.com. Change the `server_name` into.

```html
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/ubuntu/mywebsite/staticfiles/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.....  Works now.. I wasted so much time on this. I really appreciate the help

Comment: You can also add: server_name mywebsite.com *.mywebsite.com; to allow traffic from www.mywebsite.com and also from anything.mywebsite.com.